# Kubernetes on AWS dedicated host - Can I use kubectl on an existing cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, dedicated-server

I have an app with several containers running just fine using kubernetes on AWS however now I need to port this to a AWS Dedicated Host VPC where the cluster has previously been created NOT using Kubernetes so I am not able to execute kube-up.sh or its kops equivalent

Is it possible to orchestrate my containers using kubernetes on a pre-existing cluster ? ( IE. have kubernetes probe the parent AWS cluster and treat it as if it created it )

Of course until this linkage is made between my calls to kubectl and the parent AWS Dedicated Host VPC it has no Kubernetes context and just times out :

> kubectl create -f   /my/app/goodie.yaml
>
> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.199.89.247:443: i/o timeout

Possible alternative would be to call kube-up.sh or kops and demand the new cluster live inside a specified AWS Dedicated Host ... alas its not apparent Kubernetes has this flexibility ... yet !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely. kubectl is just a client application and it can connect to any kubernetes cluster and orchestrate it.

If you get i/o timeout, you most likely have connectivity issues and some firewall/proxy in place. Did you try to just access the kubernetes API through curl or telnet?

Comment: the AWS virtual-private-cloud Dedicated Host was not created using Kubernetes

Comment: Ah, I see. The "previously created cluster" that you mention is not a kubernetes cluster, just EC2 nodes. So, there is no existing kubernetes cluster on top of this AWS Dedicated Host and you would like to it setup and use kubectl to work with it.

Comment: I think this would require a bit more manual work: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/
You can also have a look at OpenShift Origin, where you can initialize such cluster using ansible scripts: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible